# Delete to line start in phpStorm

Tags: workflow, phpstorm, keymapping

Maybe I’m just an idiot, but can I set a shortcut for «delete to line start» in phpStorm
Im use to this being cmd+delete but I can’t seem to figure out how to set this in phpStorm.

Comment: I do not see any "Delete to line start" action available in "Preferences | Keymap" -- I only see "Delete to line END" ...

Comment: To bad... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well .. you can record a macro that does such job (`Shift+Home` and then `Delete`) and assign some shortcut to it -- should work.

Comment: You can now post it as an answer so that other users who need the same functionality would find it (answered questions have better rank/priority)

Comment: I’m new to using stack overflow. Where to I do this? :S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well .. you can record a macro that does such job (Shift+Home and then Delete) and assign some shortcut to it -- should work. –  LazyOne

Answer (score 2):

Try as the below:

```
ctrl + Y
```

It's OK for me.

Comment: This answers is much better!